# Python regex if present or else in Zapier workflow

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, zapier

I am working on creating a custom workflow using zapier. It requires to parse a given text using zapier formatter which uses Python Regex.

The python regex I am using is

`(?P<action>My-DATA)\s+:desc:(?P<desc>.*):\s+:priority:(?P<priority>.*):\s+:label:(?P<lbl>.*):`

Against an incoming text

`My-DATA :desc:I would like to get details from https://mydata.org/this-is-my-data: :priority:3: :label:data:`

There are couple of things which I am unable to figure out how I can achieve. Each section is delimited using `:` and section's name is also wrapped in `:`

Sometimes what happens is that the text will come in without the ending `:` for the section like this
`My-DATA :desc:I would like to get details from https://mydata.org/this-is-my-data :priority:3 :label:data`

This text is missing `:` at the end of each section, but each new section always starts with `:` followed by the name of the section.

I am trying to figure out a regex which can still work as this one with or without the section ending `:`

Working regex example is at https://regex101.com/r/T2UJcP/2

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?P<action>My-DATA)\s+:desc:(?P<desc>.*?):?\s+:priority:(?P<priority>.*?):?\s+:lbl:(?P<lbl>.*?):?\s*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `:?` to the end each section which will indicate the ending colon is optional. It can match it if it's there or not.

`(?P<action>My-DATA) :desc:(?P<desc>.+):?\s+:priority:(?P<priority>.+):?\s+:label:(?P<lbl>.+):?`

Comment: I tried that, but what happens is that ```:``` becomes part of the text of the section. Check this. Please check this https://regex101.com/r/T2UJcP/4

Comment: How about using a `*` which can be 0 or more? https://regex101.com/r/T2UJcP/5